# How to see what git merge has done before commit?

Tags: git

Say you've done a merge:

```
git checkout mybranch
git merge master
```

then edited some files manually to deal with merge conflits.

`git status` will show all the files which have been modified, but `git diff` only appears to show changes in the files you've edited for merge conflicts. How can you see the changes relative to `mybranch` which the merge has introduced, *before* you commit the whole lot (after which I think you can just do `git diff HEAD^ HEAD`).

Coming from a mercurial background here so I am probably missing some concepts ...

Comment: Could you post an example output of `git status` at that point? I think I have an answer, but I'm not sure how to recreate the situation you're describing. BTW stashes might have the same problem.

Comment: `git add <conflicted_files> && git diff --cached`.

Comment: ah great - looks like `git diff --cached` shows the just non-conflicting changes the merge made, so actually that works for me even without the add. I'd accept that as an answer if you want the points!

Comment: The "concept that's missing" is Git's "staging area".  An extremely *useful* concept.  Instead of just "committed" or "uncommitted", a "commit" in git is performed in two steps: staging and actual commit.  Here's why: [What does 'stage' mean in git?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/119782/what-does-stage-mean-in-git)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The usual way to see diffs of staged files is

```
git diff --cached
```

It should work here as well